# I dont want to show duplicate rows on output

Tags: sql

UPDATE:

Below is my query:

```
   $questionquery = "
SELECT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT(an.Answer ORDER BY an.Answer SEPARATOR ' ') AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
       q.QuestionMarks 
  FROM Answer an 
  INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId
  JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
  JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
      WHERE ".implode(" AND ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "q.QuestionContent LIKE ?"))."
      GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, Answer, r.ReplyType, q.QuestionMarks
      ORDER BY ".implode(", ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ?, 1, 0) DESC"))."
    ";
```

The above query will provide a search on a string and output the rows which contains that string under the "Question" column.

I have a [URL](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text15.php) you can access on my application, please follow the steps below in order to use the application:

- Step 1: When you open application, you see a green plus button on the
  page, click on it and it will display a modal window.
- Step 2: In modal window there is a search bar, type in "AAA" and
  submit search, you will see a bunch of rows appear.

Now as you can see if you read carefully there are some rows which re exact duplicates, as in having the exact same content within each column (same question, answer, marks, number of replies etc all the same)

This is what I want to get rid of. I don;t want it to show duplicate rows but to simply just show one of those rows so it doesn't output duplicate row. What do I need to change?

Comment: user1517628, may I suggest you rephrase your question to explain what you're trying to achieve? It's possible the solution doesn't involve DISTINCT.

Comment: question is rephrased with examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not show duplicate rows, unless I'm missing something, you just need to add the DISTINCT clause, like this:

```
$questionquery = "
SELECT DISTINCT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers,
    GROUP_CONCAT(an.Answer ORDER BY an.Answer SEPARATOR ' ') AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
    q.QuestionMarks 
FROM Answer an 
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId
JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
WHERE ".implode(" AND ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "q.QuestionContent LIKE ?"))."
GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, Answer, r.ReplyType, q.QuestionMarks
ORDER BY ".implode(", ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ?, 1, 0) DESC"))."
";
```

Comment: I don't think question id should be distinct tho because 2 exact same rows can have different questionIds, I just want all the columns except questionId to be DISTINCT. is this possible?

Comment: If 2 rows have all columns with the same values and only QuestionId is different, the rows *are distinct*, so the 2 rows will be selected using the DISTINCT clause. Please notice that DISTINCT applies to the whole row (tuple). In other words, it's not the "columns" that are distinct, it's the *rows*. If all else fails, and it it simplifies your understandig, use a subselect like SELECT DISTINCT S1.FIELD1, S1.FIELD2, S1.FIELD3 FROM (SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3... INNER JOIN ETC) S1 and you'll be sure to get only distinct rows back. Or, a better idea, split your SELECT in more granular views.

Comment: It is ok, realised that I did not need to select QuestionId, that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Following the changes to your question

Based on your example data it's simply this..

```
SELECT
  `Question`,
  `Answer`,
  `Number of Marks`
FROM
  yourQuery
GROUP BY
  `Question`,
  `Answer`,
  `Number of Marks`
```

But that leads me to suspect that there is something else the you are not telling us?

Comment: let me rephrase my question above so you know what is exactly happening.

Comment: @user1517628 - Please also include example input and desired output.

Comment: Question is rephrased, is this better?

Comment: @user1517628 - New nswer posted, but I'm not sure how that example relates to the question title...

Comment: It is still showing duplicate rows when it is same question, answer, marks etc, I will post the whole sql in my question and I will provde you a URL with steps to follow and you can see what is happening :) give me 5 mins

Comment: Something is still not right with the question. The answer to the updated sample data could simply be:
SELECT DISTINCT \`Question\`, \`Answer\`, \`Number of Marks\` FROM yourQuery

Comment: Question is updated, hopefully this would help now :)

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason for grouping by q.SessionId and Answer? I would expect there to be duplicate rows in your result set if you group by a field that you do not select (q.SessionID) and grouping by Answer sounds wrong since it is the result of an aggregate function.

Comment: No reason I was just testing group bys and seeing what was happening

Comment: my previous GROUP BY which I have now gone back to is QuestionId and SessionId